# Understanding negative scrollbar adjustment

Tags: javascript, scrollbar

I'm seeing this code in a popular javascript library **perfect-scrollbar** but really not getting this as why it made the scrollleft to -1 and then again original. Even if I print `element.scrollLeft` right after `element.scrollLeft = -1`, I get it 0.

```
var element = document.getElementById('something');
var isNegativeScroll = (function () {
    var originalScrollLeft = element.scrollLeft;
    var result = null;
    element.scrollLeft = -1;
    result = element.scrollLeft < 0;
    element.scrollLeft = originalScrollLeft;
    return result;
  })();
  var negativeScrollAdjustment = isNegativeScroll ? element.scrollWidth - element.clientWidth : 0;
```

Can anybody make me understand what does the entire code do and why it has been done so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code just checks if negative values accepted...

As far as I know negative scroll values are posible at ios safari, when scrolling with touch events with momentum scrolling.

=======

UPDATE:

This commit where this function appears:
https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar/commit/3dbf20a5d0a7563dfbb77410e4de2d94c401f6de

Seems like it is done to support RTL content...